# How to filter and add paging, if we must not expose IQueryable at Repository pattern?

Tags: repository, filtering, paging

In many discussion I learnt that was undesirable (forbidden) to expose IQueryable from Respository pattern.

What is the best practice then for server-side filtering and paging?

Comment: "Best practice" depends on your actual requirements. You need to do something very different if your filtering requirement is "allow filtering by one value of one dimension" or "allow essentially arbitrary filters on all dimensions at once".

Comment: You could consider not using a repository at all for queries. I agree with @PhilipKendall that without requirements this question is not answerable.

Comment: The most obvious is to pass in the paging information into the repository. There is also idea of not using repository at all, as it is argued to be a useless abstraction.

Comment: This is not meaningfully answerable without a concrete example. As it currently stands, you're asking us to fully explain an entire architecture. An answer that is appropriately as broad as your question itself is, would be "by using method parameters".

Comment: @RikD: In discussions like these, "repository" is just a synonym for "persistence service". Whether that's an actual repository, a query object, or similar is mostly irrelevant - it's always some kind of logic container in the persistence layer. So while you are right that you can avoid the repository _pattern_ if you want to, you'll always have some kind of persistence logic, which is what "repository" here refers to.

Answer (score 1):

The repository could offer methods that allow the application to perform paging and filtering.

The point of the repository is that it simulates an in-memory collection of all the domain objects, and offers domain-level operations to the rest of the application. The “model”, i.e. the business logic, should not have to concern itself with database-level operations.

Pagination and filtering is likely to be a domain-level concern in your application. It could indeed be that your business logic needs a domain-level concept such as a Page or Cursor that you can somehow represent. The repository would then return such a data model.

```cs
class ProductRepository {
  ...
  public Pagination StartPagination(parameters) { ... }
  public List<Product> ReadPage(Pagination p, int pageNo) { ... }
}
```

Filters can be very tricky though if the structure of the filter can be complex, e.g. arbitrary boolean expressions. In the simplest case the structure of your filters is fixed and just have some placeholders, e.g. `Repository.FindUsersWithMinAccountAge(Duration minAge)`. In more complex cases you could create a domain model that describes the filter, e.g.:

```cs
var criteria = new ProductCriteria();
criteria.Add(ProductCriteria.COLOR, "black");
criteria.AddRange(ProductCriteria.PRICE, 50, 200);
var products = repository.FindProductsMatching(criteria, limit: 25);
```

Creating a repository that allows database-agnostic access is difficult, and might not be worth it. Domain Driven Design is great for complicated applications with a substantial domain model, e.g. because there is lots of business logic. DDD and the Repository pattern is likely overkill for a CRUD app that just translates web requests to database queries and has little own business logic.

Comment: _"Creating a repository that allows database-agnostic access is difficult, and might not be worth it."_ +1 for this alone. And I'd offer that if it was worth the effort, someone would've already created it and we'd all be using it, even if only to bypass the drudgery of these kinds of business-vs-persistence discussions.